# NSUserdefaults saves null string but the string is not null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
-(void)addPower:(NSString *)newPower{
    newPower = [newPower lowercaseString];
    for(int i=0; i<[powers count]; i++){
        NSString *p = [powers objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* count = p;
        NSRange endRange = [p rangeOfString:@" "];
        NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, endRange.location);
        p = [p substringWithRange:searchRange];

        endRange = [count rangeOfString:@" "];
        count = [count substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(endRange.location, count.length-p.length)];
        if([newPower isEqualToString:p]){
            NSString *addNewPower = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i",newPower,count.integerValue+1];
            [powers replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:addNewPower];
            [ud setValue:addNewPower forKey:productName];
            NSLog(@"NEW POWER ADDED: %@ ||| %@\n",addNewPower,productName);
            NSLog(@"NEW POWER UD: %@\n",[ud stringForKey:productName]);
        }
    }
    [ud synchronize];
}
```

The output is;

NEW POWER ADDED: snap 4 ||| snap

NEW POWER UD: (null)

and when i load the Userdefault again after relaunching the app on my phone, it replaces what was supposed to be "snap 4" with just "1"

i dont understand why its not saving my user defaults.

EDIT:
forgot to mention, ud is set in the initializer & i tried setObject forKey and still got the same results

Comment: It seems that `ud` itself is `nil`. Also, don't use `setValue:forKey:`, use `setObject:forKey:` instead.

Comment: where you have declared **ud** variable?

Comment: forgot to mention, ud is set in the initializer & i tried setObject forKey and still got the same results @H2CO3

Comment: forgot to mention, ud is set in the initializer & i tried setObject forKey and still got the same results @Yashesh

Comment: Check the return value of `synchronize` for errors. You might also want to register your defaults.

Comment: the reason for returning null may probably be because of the productName variable. it seems nothing illegal or problematic as seen in the code. i can just advice you to print the productName value while saving and after reading from userDefaults

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[ud setValue:addNewPower forKey:@"productName"];
```

Try this....may be help full for u...

Comment: You should use `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ud = [NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults]; try making ud a property of the class and access it by using self.ud everywhere in your class.

in your .h

```
{
    NSUserdefaults *ud;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSUserdefaults *ud;
```

then in your .m

```
@synthesize ud;
```

then when you init

```
self.ud = [NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Comment: You don't need the ivar or the `@synthesize`, just the `@property`. And the property, if desired, should be declared in the .m file, not the .h unless you want other classes to access the property. And why `weak`? This should be a `strong` property.

Comment: The problem isn't accessing the UD object, it's figuring out why the strings aren't setting in it @scott D

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this.I think this will work fine.Yes ofcourse you cant get value becoz you didn't synchronise it first so plz synchronise first it and then print it.

```
[ud setValue:addNewPower forKey:productName];
[[ud standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"NEW POWER ADDED: %@ ||| %@\n",addNewPower,productName);
NSLog(@"NEW POWER UD: %@\n",[ud stringForKey:productName]);
```

Comment: Nah, nope, [the same problem](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4960980/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-06%20at%207.40.40%20AM.png) as that of with ThXou's answer.

Comment: i can't identify your problem.So please explain.I'll help you sure.

Comment: @Dhambir The value is set even without `synchronize`, it's just not written to disk.

Comment: Yes i know it but he wanna change value so in that case you should do it.

Comment: But that's not the problem of OP, his values are - seemingly - not even set in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your defaults:

Create a new plist in your bundle. (Drag and drop maybe - if you already have a plist file containing the defaults)

Then in the beginning of the application:

```
 NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaults" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dict];
```

Then you have a more fail-safe of doing things.

Answer (score -3):

That's because the `syncronize` is not instantly. Try to put the `NSLog` after this line:

```
[ud syncronize];
```

And you will see that it works fine.

Comment: Huh, what? That affects the writing to file only.

Comment: From Apple:

    `The synchronize method, which is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, keeps the in-memory cache in sync with a user’s defaults database.`

So, you call `syncronize` to avoid having to wait the automátic syncronize.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't prevent the in-memory values from being set already and immediately.

Comment: Are you sure?, read the documentation before down vote my answer man. Try it your self and you'll see it.

Comment: Also, you stop serial downvoting my questions ***now.***

Comment: You have a serious problem man. Ok, you are right, you`ve demostrate your answer, bravo!. But, it was my case, and the value doesn't updated until i call `sincronize`, and the documentation supports me. If you don't have how to read, i understand, but don't say that i don't know what i'm talking.